# Prove $\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(2n x)\,\cot x\,\mathrm{d}x- \int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(2n x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

> Let $$a_n=\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(2n x)\,\cot x\,\mathrm{d}x ~~~\textrm{ and} ~~~   b_n=\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(2n x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$
>   Prove that $a_n-b_n \to 0.$

*Attempt.* We have that 
$$a_n-b_n  = \int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(2n x)\,\left(\cot x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$
Integration by parts would give:
$$a_n-b_n=\left[\log\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\sin(2nx)\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-2n\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(2n x)\,\log\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=-2n\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(2n x)\,\log\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ but this doesn't seem to go any further.

On the other hand, from [Integral $\int_0^\pi \cot(x/2)\sin(nx)\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321919/integral-int-0-pi-cotx-2-sinnx-dx) we have $a_n=\frac{\pi}{2}$, so:

$$b_n-a_n=\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{\sin(2n x)}{x}-1\right)\,\mathrm{d}x,$$
so:
$$|b_n-a_n|\leqslant \int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left|\frac{\sin(2n x)}{x}-1\right|\,\mathrm{d}x,$$
but I also didn't manage to get this any further.

Thanks in advance for the help.

---

Edit. Consequence of the above limit is the evaluation of the Dirichlet integral: $$\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=
\lim_{n \to +\infty}b_n=\lim_{n \to +\infty}a_n=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: Why don't you apply the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma

Comment: I had in my mind an elementary proof, if possible of course, that would use only tools such as integration by parts, boundness arguments etc.

Comment: You've made a mistake somewhere, as $\log (-\sin x/x)$ is not defined on this interval.

Comment: You can prove the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma for $C^1$ functions by very elementary means (integration by parts).

Comment: @zhw of course, just edited.

Comment: Lord Shark the Unknown, you are right, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

N.B.: I think it's good, but I'm tired, so it might be wrong. I'm going to check it after I wake up; read it carefully until then.

Let $f(x)=\cot(x)-\frac{1}{x}$ with $f(0)=0$.
We have that
\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^{\pi/2}f(x)\sin(2nx)\mathrm{d}x\right|
&=\left|-\int_0^{\pi/2}f'(x)\frac{\cos(2nx)}{2n}\mathrm{d}x+\left[\frac{f(x)\cos(2nx)}{2n}\right]_0^{\pi/2}\right|\\
&=\left|-\int_0^{\pi/2}f'(x)\frac{\cos(2nx)}{2n}\mathrm{d}x+\left(-\frac{2}{\pi}\right)\frac{\cos(n \pi)}{2n}\right|\\
&=\left|-\int_0^{\pi/2}f'(x)\frac{\cos(2nx)}{2n}\mathrm{d}x-\frac{(-1)^n}{n \pi}\right|\\
&\leqslant \left|\int_0^{\pi/2}f'(x)\frac{\cos(2nx)}{2n}\mathrm{d}x\right|+\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n\pi}\right| \\
&\leqslant \int_0^{\pi/2}\left|f'(x)\frac{\cos(2nx)}{2n}\right|\mathrm{d}x+\frac{1}{n\pi}\\
&\leqslant \int_0^{\pi/2}\left|C\frac{\cos(2nx)}{2n}\right|\mathrm{d}x+\frac{1}{n\pi}\\
&\leqslant \frac{C}{2n}\int_0^{\pi/2}\left|\cos(2nx)\right|\mathrm{d}x+\frac{1}{n\pi}\\
&\leqslant \frac{C}{2n}\int_0^{\pi/2}1\mathrm{d}x+\frac{1}{n\pi}\\
&\leqslant \frac{\pi C}{4n}+\frac{1}{n\pi} \to 0
\end{align}
Since the absolute value of the derivative of $f$ on $[0, \pi/2]$ is bounded by a constant $C$.

Comment: Imagine if you were not tired. Totally fine indeed. Thank you!