# A uniform bound by an integrable function for a Fourier series' partial sums.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Consider
  \begin{equation}
    \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}=-\log|2\sin x/2|~~~ \big(x\in(0,2\pi)\big),
  \end{equation}
and its $2\pi$-periodic extension $f$ (for a proof of the above identity see [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321736/the-fourier-series-sum-n-1-infty-1-n-cos-nx).) Notice that $f\in L^1(0,\pi)$, since $f(x)\sim\log(x)~(x\rightarrow0)$. This Fourier series is not absolutely or uniformly convergent.

*My problem is to show that every one of the partial sums
  \begin{equation}
    s_N(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}
  \end{equation}
is bounded in absolute value by the same function $h\in L^1(0,\pi)$. I.e., $|s_N(x)|\leq h(x)$ for every $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\in(0,\pi)$.*

The various things I have tried so far mostly involve writing the partial sums using the [Dirichlet kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel)
  \begin{equation}
    D_N(x)=\frac{\sin(N+1/2)x}{2\sin x/2}=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^N\cos(nx).
  \end{equation}
Then, using that $f$ is even and $2\pi$-periodic,
  \begin{align}
    \pi s_N(x) &=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)D_N(t-x)\text dt \\
               &=\int_0^\pi\big(f(y+x)+f(y-x)\big)D_N(y)\text dy \\
               &=\int_0^\pi \underbrace{\log\left|\frac{\sin(y-x)/2}{\sin(y+x)/2}\right|}_{\displaystyle{:=g(x,y)}}
                  D_N(y)\text dy.
  \end{align}
We may differentiate $g$ to find
  \begin{equation}
    \partial_yg(x,y)=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x-\cos y}.
  \end{equation}
Hence, integrating by parts,
  \begin{align}
    \pi s_N(x)=\left[g(x,y)\int_x^yD_N\right]_{y=0}^{y=\pi} -\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin x\int_x^yD_N}{\cos x-\cos y}\text dy.
  \end{align}
The boundary terms vanish since $g(x,y)$ vanishes when $y=0,\pi$, so if we write $\int_x^yD_N=K_N(x,y)$ then
  \begin{equation}
    \pi s_N(x)=-\int_0^\pi K_N(x,y)\partial_yg(x,y)\text dy.
  \end{equation}

Observe that $\partial_yg(x,y)$ is singular as $y\rightarrow x$, and indeed, by Taylor-expanding $\cos y$ around $x$, behaves like
  \begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{y-x}\big(1+O(y-x)\big).
  \end{equation}
Clearly, then, one needs to prove that $K_N(x,y)$ will "kill" $(y-x)^{-1}$ in some uniform fashion as $y\rightarrow x$ (and $N\rightarrow\infty$!). Unfortunately using the $\sin$-representation of $D_N$ to Taylor-expand $K_N$ around $y=x$ gives
  \begin{equation}
    K_N(x,y)=D_N(x)\int_x^y\big(1+N\cdot O(t-x)\big)\text dt=
             D_N(x)(y-x)\big(1+N\cdot O(y-x)\big),
  \end{equation}
where I have left out the factor $N$ from the $O$-term to illustrate the non-uniformity of the convergence.

There are a couple of other failed attempts I made in a similar vein (for example using the $\cos$-representation of $D_N$), but for fear of making this post too long, I will leave them out. Any ideas on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated, though I would prefer them left as ideas, and not fully fleshed-out answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added to the answer to provide, I believe,  a clear way forward.  Please let me know how I can improve the answer as I just want to help and give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here is the sketch on an idea only.

Step $1$

Start with the partial sums

$$s_N(x) =\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\cos nx}{n}$$

---

Step $2$

Differentiate $s_N$ term by term to arrive at

$s_N'(x) =-\sum_{n=1}^N \sin nx= -\csc (x/2) \sin(Nx/2)\sin((N+1)x/2)$

---

Step $3$

Using the closed-form expression for $s_N'(x)$, express $s_N(x)$ as an integral of $s_N'$ as

$$s_N(x)=s_N(\pi)+\int_{\pi}^x s_N'(x')dx'$$

where $-1\ge s_N(\pi)<-1/2$.

---

Step $4$

Find a bound for the integral of $s_N'$.

$$\begin{align}\left|\int_{\pi}^x s_N'(x')dx'\right|&= \left|\,\int_{\pi}^x \left(-\csc (x'/2) \sin(Nx'/2)\sin((N+1)x'/2)\right)\,dx'\,\right|\\\\
&\le \int_{x}^{\pi} \left|-\csc (x'/2) \sin(Nx'/2)\sin((N+1)x'/2)\right|\,dx'\\\\
&\le\int_x^{\pi} \csc (x'/2) \,dx'\\\\
&=2\log\left(\cot\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)\right)
\end{align}$$

So, choose $h(x) =|s_N(\pi)|+2\log\left(\cot\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)\right)$, which is an $L^1$ function on $(0,\pi)$ since $h \sim 2\log(x)$ for small $x$.

Note:  $2\log\left(\cot\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)\right)\ge 0$ on $(0,\pi)$.

---

Hints for Other Possible Ways Forward:

$$\sin(Nx/2)\sin((N+1)x/2)=\frac12\left(\cos(x/2)-\cos((N+1/2)x)\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Unless I'm missing something vital, as far as I can see, it leads to the bound
$$|s_N(x)|\leq|s_N(\pi)|+\int_\pi^x \left|\frac{\cos(N+1/2)t-\cos t/2}{2\sin t/2}\right| \text dt.$$
The integral in this is finite for each fixed $x$, but suffers in that the integrand has leading-order behaviour
$$N^2t$$
as $t\rightarrow0$, so its (the integral's) limit as $N\rightarrow\infty$ might not itself be integrable. Please could you elaborate?

Comment: I apologise profusely: there was a mix-up between the limit function $f$ and the bounding function; I had erroneously labelled them the same, and I have corrected this now.

Comment: Of course you don't really believe that $\cos (N+1/2)t -\cos t/2$ can exceed $2$, do you?  So, the integral is bounded by both $\int_{\pi}^x \csc (t/2) dt$ which integrates to ... and $\frac12 \int_{\pi}^x (\csc(t/2)+\cot(t/2))dt$ which integrates to ...  Please let me know how I can help further.

Comment: OK, that's some obvious estimating I rather should have noticed, thanks! However, unless I'm mistaken, I calculate
$$\int_x^\pi\csc\frac{t}{2}\text dt=\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\csc\frac{x}{2} +\cot\frac{x}{2}\right)\sim-\log x~~~(x\rightarrow0).$$
Integrability of $h$ then follows. I would be happy to make your answer official if you correct this. Thanks, once again!

Comment: Apologies, I see that $\cot x/2=\csc x+\cot x$, and also I made an error in my integration. All is well!

Comment: @Stromael  Please to hear! And I really hope that this met your needs.

Comment: It did indeed. The only further comment I have is that you could mention that the closed-form expression for $s_N'(x)$ comes directly from the well-known properties of the conjugate Dirichlet kernel.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, h depends on N and is not for all N. Suggest taking out the first term and replace by an appropriate constant + absolute value of the alternating sum $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{( - 1)}^n}\frac{1}{n}} $ .  Actually a bounding function for the partial sum can be taken to be the function plus 9/2

Answer (score 0):

Young's inequality (see [Alzer](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs10476-005-0006-1.pdf), for instance) gives:
$$ s_N(x)\geq -1 \tag{1}$$
and summation by parts gives:
$$ s_N(x) = \frac{1}{N}\left(D_N(x)-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{D_n(x)-\frac{1}{2}}{n(n+1)}\tag{2} $$
hence the claim follows from [the fact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel) that:
$$ \| D_N \|_{L^1}=O(\log n). \tag{3}$$
The trick is just to locate the real roots of $D_N$ to be able to state:
$$ \left|D_N(x)\right|\leq \min\left(N,\frac{C}{x}\right).\tag{4}$$

Comment: Thank you. I don't quite see why $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{D_n(x)}{n(n+1)}$ should be absolutely convergent; I think this is needed for your reasoning to show there is a bound of every $s_N$ by a single $L^1$ function.

Comment: @Stromael: it is absolutely convergent over any compact subset of $(0,\pi]$ by $(4)$.

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid my understanding has worsened: why must $(4)$ hold, and why is the resulting bounding function in $L^1(0,\pi)$? By my calculations, if $M=\min\{n\geq1/x\}$, then
$$|S_N(x)|<3+C(2M+1/2+1/3+...+1/M).$$

Comment: I apologise profusely: there was a mix-up between the limit function $f$ and the bounding function; I had erroneously labelled them the same, and I have corrected this now.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider complex variable technique and Abel summable method.

Starting with
$f(z) = Log(1 - z) =  - \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{\frac{z}{n}}^n}} $

we get

$f(r{e^{i\theta }}) =  - \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\cos (n\theta )}}{n}{r^n}}  - i\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\sin (n\theta )}}{n}{r^n}} $

and so

${\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} Log(1 - r{e^{i\theta }}) =  - \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\cos (n\theta )}}{n}{r^n}} $.

Since $ - \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\cos (n\theta )}}{n}} $ is convergent for $\theta$  not a multiple of 2 $\pi$, by Abel’s theorem,

$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\cos (n\theta )}}{n}}  =  - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{r \to {1^ - }} {\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} Log(1 - r{e^{i\theta }})$ .

But

${\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} Log(1 - r{e^{i\theta }}) = \ln (|1 - r{e^{i\theta }}|) = \frac{1}{2}\ln (1 + {r^2} - 2r\cos (\theta ))$

and so

$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{r \to {1^ - }} {\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} Log(1 - r{e^{i\theta }}) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{r \to {1^ - }} \frac{1}{2}\ln (1 + {r^2} - 2r\cos (\theta )) = \frac{1}{2}\ln (2 - 2\cos (\theta )) = \frac{1}{2}\ln (4{\sin ^2}({\textstyle{\theta  \over 2}})) = \ln (2\sin ({\textstyle{\theta  \over 2}}))$

Thus 
$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\cos (n\theta )}}{n}}  =  - \ln (2\sin ({\textstyle{\theta  \over 2}})) = \ln \left( {\frac{1}{{2\sin ({\textstyle{\theta  \over 2}})}}} \right)$ .

To show that the convergence is dominated by a integrable function, you can use the Fejer sum. For the detail please see  Theorem 11 of

*Riemann summable everywhere series, Two special cosine series and Abel summable series*
https://037598a680dc5e00a4d1feafd699642badaa7a8c.googledrive.com/host/0B4HffVs7117IbmZ2OTdKSVBZLVk/Fourier%20Series/R-Summability%20two%20cosine%20series.pdf

Indeed

$\left| {{t_n}(\theta )} \right| = \left| {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{\cos (k\theta )}}{k}} } \right| \le \ln \left( {\frac{1}{{2\sin \left( {{\textstyle{\theta  \over 2}}} \right)}}} \right) + \frac{9}{2}$  .

All you have to do is just to add the constant 9/2 to the function and this is the required function. The details are in the above article.